# Pytorch optimizer message: "API has changed, `state_steps` argument must contain a list of singleton tensors"

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, python-multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, gradienttape

I am trying to implement an A3C reinforcement learning program, I am using as boilerplate the code from [MorvanZhou](https://github.com/MorvanZhou/pytorch-A3C). However it seems like the pytorch optimizer now uses Singletons instead of integers (Whatever that means) according to [this issue I found](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairscale/issues/1083).

I have a Net class exactly the same as the A3C example and I am calculating the loss from the Net's loss function like so:

```
    def v_wrap(np_array, dtype=np.float32):
       if np_array.dtype != dtype:
           np_array = np_array.astype(dtype)
       return torch.from_numpy(np_array)
```

```
    
    loss = lnet.loss_func(
        v_wrap(np.vstack(bs)),
        v_wrap(np.vstack(ba)),
        v_wrap(np.array(buffer_v_target)[:, None]))

    # calculate local gradients and push local parameters to global
    opt.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    for lp, gp in zip(lnet.parameters(), gnet.parameters()):
        gp._grad = lp.grad
    opt.step()
```

It continues correctly but in the line `opt.step()` it throws the exception:

`RuntimeError: API has changed, "state_steps" argument must contain a list of singleton tensors`

I saw in the [issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairscale/issues/1083) they make a quick fix by getting the state_dict() of the optimizer and then converting it back to a singleton.

```
            osd = optimizer.state_dict()
            for _, bufs in osd["state"].items():
                if "step" in bufs.keys():
                    # convert state_step back from int into a singleton tensor
                    bufs["step"] = torch.tensor(bufs["step"])
```

I am just not sure where I am converting these values into an integer or where can I apply that "fix"

For context: I am running a text-based simulation in a torch.multiprocessing process which runs the whole episode and then attempts to calculate the loss and the gradients from the memory of Actions, states and rewards of each step. It has a global net and a global optimizer which uses the gradients to update the global network parameters.

The global optimizer is this one:

```
import torch


class SharedAdam(torch.optim.Adam):
    def __init__(self, params, lr=1e-3, betas=(0.9, 0.99), eps=1e-8,
                 weight_decay=0):
        super(SharedAdam, self).__init__(params, lr=lr, betas=betas, eps=eps, weight_decay=weight_decay)
        # State initialization
        for group in self.param_groups:
            for p in group['params']:
                state = self.state[p]
                state['step'] = 0
                state['exp_avg'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)
                state['exp_avg_sq'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)

                # share in memory
                state['exp_avg'].share_memory_()
                state['exp_avg_sq'].share_memory_()
```

The whole code is in this git repo folder in case it helps: https://github.com/SebsCubs/energy-plus-DRL/tree/deep_copy/A3C_refactor

I tried to change the state to my specific environment, the simulation runs fine, the memory is saved correctly and I was expecting to be able to update the global network with the optimizer but I have not been able to properly do so.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when implementing A3C with torch 1.13.1. Solved this by using torch==1.11.0.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line 'state['step'] = 0' to 'state['step'] = torch.zeros(1)' worked for me.